# XCode error: failed to launch -- 'A' packet returned an error: -1

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I have recently upgraded to XCode 5, since I upgraded the iOS Simulators stopped working. They simply wouldn't launch my app. I can run it off of my device no problem, but the simulators won't work. Since I can run it on my device, this is no problem... however when I try to write a command line application, I'm given this error:

XCode error: failed to launch TestApplication -- 'A' packet returned an error: -1

This even happens when I try to run the command line template that is generated by Xcode when I create a new project... as in the blank "Hello World" command line project.

On another machine, XCode 5 works just fine. There's not much of a technical difference between the two machines. Both are Macbook Pros.

Has anyone encountered this or does anyone know the cause or how this can be resolved?